# Error creating recovery drive, unable to to create recovery drive

Tags: windows-10

Using the recovery drive creation wizard, get the error below:

"We can't create the recovery drive -- a problem occurred while creating the recovery drive"

[image]

I have rebooted and retried, etc.

I believe that, while the system runs Win10 fine and boots without issue, that the windows recovery partition on the hard drive may be incomplete in some way. So perhaps this question is: How to repair the windows recovery partition? (This is after upgrading a win 7 system to win 10)

What steps to take?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem a couple of times. The problem was with the VSS writer having problems creating a system image.

Use Event Viewer to see if anything is logged when it fails. In my case, amongst others, was

```
AddLegacyDriverFiles: Unable to back up image of binary Microsoft Link-Layer Discovery Protocol.
```

Microsoft suggested this might be a third party driver problem. On one device disabling LLDP in the wireless adapter allowed the recovery drive creation to proceed.

[image]

On another device this didn't work. Microsoft have filed a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

The recovery partition may be corrupted, removed or inaccessible for some reason. You may have to purchase recovery disks from your computer manufacturer or put a warranty call in for them to investigate the issue.

Comment: This seems more of a comment then anything.  Of course I think any answer that doesn't highlight the fact, that a Windows Installation disk contains the same WinRE that Windows Recovery disk contains isn't all that helpful.